# use of parent's function (inheritance c++)

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have four .cpp files, `Animal, Cattle, Sheep, DrugAdmin`.
`Animal` is parent class of `Cattle`, and it has `calcDose()`, which calculates the amount of dose. `DrugAdmin` is main function.
The thing is, I want to use `calcDose()` function differently (Cattle, Sheep) and no `calcDose()` function is needed for `Animal` class. However, every time I try to use  `calcDose()`, it automatically calls function in `Animal` class even when I want to use under `Cattle` class. This is the code I have done so far. (I've cut it down)

**Animal.cpp**

```
#include "Animal.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Animal::Animal(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, char newsex, vector<Treatment> treatArray)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    yy = yy;
    mm = mm;
    dd = dd;
    accDose = 0;
    sex = newsex;
}
double Animal::calcDose(){
    return 0;
}
```

**Cattle.cpp**

```
#include "Cattle.h"
using namespace std;


Cattle::Cattle(int newid, double newweight, int yy, int mm, int dd, 
           char newsex, vector<Treatment> newtreatArray, string newcategory)
    : Animal(newid, newweight, yy,mm,dd, newsex, newtreatArray)
{
    id = newid;
    weight = newweight;
    accDose = 0;
    sex = newsex;
    Cattle::category = newcategory;
}

Cattle::~Cattle(){}

double Cattle::calcDose(){
    if(getDaysDifference() < 90 || getCategory() == "Meat"){
        accDose = 0;
        return accDose;
    }
    else if(getCategory() == "Dairy"){
        if (weight < 250 || accDose > 200){
            accDose = 0;
        }
        else{
            accDose = weight * 0.013 + 46;
        }
        return accDose;
    }
    else if(getCategory() == "Breeding"){
        if (weight < 250 || accDose > 250){
            accDose = 0;
        }
        else{
            accDose = weight * 0.021 + 81;
        }
        return accDose;
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << "It is not valid category" << endl;
    }
}
```

Sheep class is pretty much same but the contents of `calcDose()`

**DrugAdmin.cpp**

```
#include "DrugAdmin.h"
using namespace std;

vector<Animal*> vec_Animal;

void addAnimal(){
    int select=0;
    int id;
    double weight;
    int yy;
    int mm;
    int dd;
    char sex;
    string category;
    vector<Treatment> treatArray;

        //user inputs all the values (i've cut it down)

     Animal* c1 = new Cattle(id,weight,yy,mm,dd,sex,treatArray,category);

        vec_Animal.push_back(c1);
}

void administerDose(int id)  //Main Problem
{


   vector<Animal*>::iterator ite_Animal = vec_Animal.begin();
    for(ite_Animal; ite_Animal != vec_Animal.end(); ++ite_Animal)
        cout<<"\nVector contains:"<< (*ite_Animal)->calcDose();
}
```

I'm sorry for the long and messed up question. Final question is, Cattle has extra data member which is `category` but the system doesn't recognise this as well. It recognises as if it is `Animal` object. Can I have a piece of advice please?

Cheers

Comment: Your last question is unclear. "system doesn't recognize it" doesn't really mean much. Compiler error? If so, where?

Comment: Mat, I really believe he means that he cannot call type specific methods from an animal object despite it being instantiated by subclass object

Comment: The first two sentences make it apparent that you are confusing files with classes. But C++ is not Java. Do you have [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)?

Comment: I've been only working with Java, I thought it'd be similar but apparently it's not..
@Mat what I meant was, for example, even if I try to call (*ite_Animal)->category; it doesn't even have any category..
I think the answer is under there but thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Java (and many other languages), C++ uses what is called "static binding" by default. Static binding means the function called is based on the declared type of the object (or pointer) at compile time, rather than what the object actually is (or what the pointer is actually pointing to).

The alternative to static binding is "dynamic binding". In dynamic binding, the function called is based on what the object actually is (or what the pointer is actually pointing to) at runtime.

To enable dynamic binding, which is what you'll want if you have an inheritance hierarchy set up and are maintaining base class pointers (Animal*s), you have to use the keyword `virtual`. `virtual` makes a function dynamically bound, so that calls to that function will reflect the actual runtime type of the object (Cattle) rather than the compile time declared pointer type (Animal*).

To declare a function virtual, you put the virtual keyword before the return value on the function declaration (in the class declaration / .h file):

```
class Animal
{
    virtual void calcDose();
    // ...
};
```

It is also good style to put virtual on the overridden function in the derived class (calcDose() in Cattle), although the virtual is implied for inherited functions, so putting it there is not strictly necessary.

The one last thing to make sure you to get dynamic binding, is to make sure you always have pointers (or references) to objects rather than objects on the stack (when you want dynamic binding). An object on the stack (i.e. Animal a) can only be it's declared type, it can't point to a derived class type. So the `vector<Animal*>` you have is perfect, because those pointers can point to Cattle objects (or Animal objects), while a vector could only hold actual animal objects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is really helpful.
Now I added virtual, but there's another error appeared.
It says, binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion). The "<<" is on the last line just before (*ite_Animal). 
Can you teach me what's wrong with it? Thanks!:)

Answer (score 5):

> every time I try to use `calcDose()`, it automatically calls function in `Animal` class

Sounds like you forgot to make `calcDose` a [`virtual` member function](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/).

> Final question is, `Cattle` has extra data member which is category but the system doesn't recognise this as well. It recognises as if it is `Animal` object.

I'm not sure what you mean by the "system" "recognizing" anything, but if you access a `Cattle` object through an `Animal*`, then you can't get to the `Cattle`-specific members. You'd have use either a `Cattle*` or, again, polymorphism/`virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your calcDose function virtual and redefine it in each subclass: Cattle, etc. Also to recognize your Animal as a Cattle you have to cast it to Cattle class. But you are supposed to use the common base type interface most of the time.